# Custom permissions in Django

Tags: python, django, jwt

In Django Rest framework, we can verify permissions such as (isAuthenticated, isAdminUser...)
but how can we add our custom permissions and decide what django can do with those permissions?

I really want to understand what happens behind (I didn't find a documentation that explaint this):

```
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I did what you said but there is no definition, I think it is because `@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])`  is a decorator : `from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
`

Comment: I deleted my comment and wrote you an answer.

Comment: You can write your own permissions and use a decorator to apply them in the viewsets

Comment: @Luiz and how do we write our own permissions is there any documentation out there?

Comment: @OussamaEddahri I wrote you an answer with a example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own permissions, like this:

```
def permission_valid_token(func):
    # first arg is the viewset, second is the request
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        valid_token, user_token = test_token_authorization(args[1].headers) # my function to validate the user
        if not valid_token:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This is a permission that i'm using in app, probably you will have to change the valid_token part

And them you import in your views

```
from file_that_you_use.permissions import permission_valid_token
```

And you use as a decorator

```
class WeatherViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @permission_valid_token
    def list(self, request):
```

This is just a viewset for example, you can use generic viewsets or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition), hover over `@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])`, click on Command (on your keyboard).

[image]

You can see what happens behind the scenes, play and create your custom Django version (not recommended) or you can overwrite the function.